# Enhance and Shrink Preg_match lines

Tags: php

I made a preg_match to get my results and it works fine but I think it can be done with simple lines instead of repeating the code

```
$input = array('http://example.com/blue-bloods-s10e13-more-text/','http://example.com/charmed-2018-s02e11-more-text/','http://example.com/dynasty-2017-s03e11-more-text/','http://example.com/magnum-p-i-2018-s02e14-more-text/','http://example.com/fresh-off-the-boat-s06e13-more-text/','http://example.com/hawaii-five-0-2010-s10e14-more-text/','http://example.com/american-housewife-s04e13-more-text/','http://example.com/love-us-s01e13-more-text/');

    foreach ($input as $value ){
preg_match('/http:\/\/example.com\/([^`]*?)-s([0-9]{2})e([0-9]{2})/', $value, $matches);

$name = $matches[1];
$cname = preg_replace('/-us/', '', $name);
$cname1 = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $cname);
$cname2 = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4})$/', '', $cname1);
$cname3 = preg_replace('/\s$/', '', $cname2);

echo $cname3."<br>";
}
```

The output is exactly like what I want

```
blue bloods
charmed
dynasty
magnum p i
fresh off the boat
Hawaii five 0
american housewife
love
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you add more information about what the input data looks like and what part of that you're interested in?

Comment: @Mask the input data already at the top of my code, the output that I wrote above is what I need, Thanks.

Comment: @Mast this looks good enough to reopen.

Comment: @Roman this looks good enough to reopen.

Comment: @mickmackusa My original comment has not be addressed, at all.

Comment: @Sammax I see that you have provided a battery of input strings and your exact desired output, but Mast wants _more_. Please edit your question to include a plain English description of what your pattern needs to do and how your strings may vary.  For instance, is it possible to have a string with `-us` followed by `-2020`? How about in the opposite order?  I would like to post an answer, but cannot while this page is closed.

Comment: @Sammax how might this show look as one of your strings? https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0389564/?ref_=m_ttls_tt_3

Comment: @ mickmackusa Good point, in this case I must improve the pattern.

Comment: Is this really gonna just hang at 4 out of 5 reopen votes?

Comment: Well, I cannot post an answer because all 4 Reopen votes have timed out.  Please edit your question then perhaps another wave of support can be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Toward optimization and better functionality

- consider using short array syntax `[]` instead of old-fashioned `array()`
- do not designate redundant captured groups such as `([0-9]{2})...([0-9]{2})` if you only need the 1st captured group `` ([^`]*?) ``
- regex `[0-9]` has a concise equivalent for designating digits - **`\d`**

All those `preg_replace` calls in the initial approach can be combined into a single call using regex alternation group `/-us|(\d{4}|\s)$/` for combining the needed patterns. 
The `\s$` patten could also be excluded from combined pattern in favor of `rtrim` function call.
As `/-/` is the only pattern that is too simple and requires different replacement string `' '` (space) - it deserves to be a simple string replacement with [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

---

The final optimized approach:

```
$input = ['http://example.com/blue-bloods-s10e13-more-text/','http://example.com/charmed-2018-s02e11-more-text/',
          'http://example.com/dynasty-2017-s03e11-more-text/','http://example.com/magnum-p-i-2018-s02e14-more-text/', 
          'http://example.com/fresh-off-the-boat-s06e13-more-text/','http://example.com/hawaii-five-0-2010-s10e14-more-text/',
          'http://example.com/american-housewife-s04e13-more-text/','http://example.com/love-us-s01e13-more-text/'];

foreach ($input as $value){
    preg_match('/http:\/\/example.com\/([^`]*?)-s\d{2}e\d{2}/', $value, $matches);
    $name = str_replace('-', ' ', preg_replace('/-us|(\d{4}|\s)$/', '', $matches[1]));
    echo $name . "<br>";
}
```

The output:

```
blue bloods
charmed
dynasty
magnum p i
fresh off the boat
hawaii five 0
american housewife
love
```